# How to connect to a remote Microsoft Azure database with JetBrains DataGrip

Tags: azure-sql-database, datagrip

I copy pasted my host, user name and password from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to the corresponding text box on JetBrains DataGrip but when I test the connection I get an error (BTW, I am able to connect to my Azure DB through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I have the "SQL Server (Microsoft" driver installed on JetBrains DataGrip).

What am I missing...?

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Please see below my reply to Lin Leng - MSFT for the error i'm getting, LMK what further details are needed.

Answer (score 3):

And i don't see a reason why you can't. Exactly what error you are seeing? It works fine during my test(datagrip 2017.1.4)
[image]

Comment: This is the error I'm receiving:
"The specified user/password combination is rejected: [S0001][40852] Cannot open database '' on server '[SERVER-NAME]' requested by the login. Access to the database is only allowed using a security-enabled connection string. ClientConnectionId:[ID-NUMBER]"

Keep in mind I am able to connect with MSSMS using the same credentials.
BTW, unlike you I'm using DataGrip Version 2017.1.5

Answer (score 1):

Please, try [DataGrip 2017.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/nextversion/), where Microsoft Azure driver is available.

[image]

Comment: I've updated to the latest release version 2017.2 with the new Azure driver.

This is the error I'm getting now:
[08S01] The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.security.cert.CertificateException: Failed to validate the server name in a certificate during Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) initialization."

Comment: @Adam please, check the settings on the server side, especially security ones.

Comment: UPDATE:
I am able to connect ad see the databases, but when I try to select the schema (tables) of a specific database I get this error:

"[S0001][40515] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Reference to database and/or server name in '[DATABASE_NAME].sys.schemas' is not supported in this version of SQL Server..
Reference to database and/or server name in '[DATABASE_NAME].sys.schemas' is not supported in this version of SQL Server."

Comment: It might have been fixed in the release version. Please, try it.

Comment: I am using the release version

Comment: Ok, got it!Please, add more information here. Screenshots, logs.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-5001